# SQL Query how to get data

Tags: sql

I have a database wherein I have the following columns:

```
id
name
date
time
item1
item2
item3
```

There are many 'names' but different 'id'. For each 'name', there are different 'date'. The 'date' may also duplicate. Under each 'date', there are different 'time'.

So an example data in the database is like this:

```
name   date       time
Name_1 2013-01-01 1:30
Name_1 2013-01-01 4:30
Name_1 2013-01-01 7:30
Name_1 2013-01-02 12:30
Name_1 2013-01-02 14:30
Name_1 2013-01-02 17:30
Name_2 2013-01-01 1:30
Name_2 2013-01-01 4:30
Name_2 2013-01-01 7:30
Name_2 2013-01-02 12:30
Name_2 2013-01-02 14:30
Name_2 2013-01-02 17:30
```

If I want my output to be:

```
Name_1 2013-01-01 7:30 /* last time checked for 2013-01-01 of Name_1 */
Name_1 2013-01-02 17:30 /* last time checked for 2013-01-02 of Name_1 */
Name_2 2013-01-01 7:30 /* last time checked for 2013-01-01 of Name_2 */
Name_2 2013-01-02 17:30 /* last time checked for 2013-01-02 of Name_2 */
```

What should be my query? Unfortunately, I cannot change the database structure anymore.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT name, date, MAX(time) FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, date
ORDER BY name,date
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/470ce/5/0

Comment: @AnachelleCasandraCastillo, then accept this/other as answer as well make it a habit to show your appreciation towards someone effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  `name`, `date`, MAX(`time`) AS last_checked
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `name`, `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know when the last check happened for each day.

You can do that with

```
Select name, date, max(time) from table_name GROUP BY name, date, ORDER BY date DESC;
```

The database design is awful though, I strongly recommend to migrate to a better design.

Comment: Thanks! I did not create this database design though :( I know it's kinda awful.